# InfoPath Forms Services - ComboBox Type-Ahead Not Working

Tags: infopath, forms-services, dropdown

We have a simple list with a Lookup to another list on a single-line-of-text field.

I customise the form with InfoPath and change the drop-down-list to Combo Box. I set the List ID as the Value and the List Title as the "Display Name". When I test the form and start typing in the Combo Box the type-ahead (custom text / pre-fill / suggestion  ) feature doesn't work properly. For example, if I paste a valid value I get the error "Only positive integers are allowed".

It's as if the Combo Box is forcing you to use the mouse to select a valid value and the auto-suggest (and paste) simply doesn't work.

Funnily enough, the paste seems to work in InfoPath Preview Mode, but not in Run Mode (via the Browser).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make **List Title** as **Value** too since ListID is always a number and value is what is used for lookup (and probably what is typed)?

Or, to change **Data type** in combobox properies to **Text(string)** if it is **Whole Number (integer)**